# Взаимодействие django и telegram Bot на flask

Tags: python, django, flask, pythonanywhere

Добрейшего всем!
Намедни я закончил переделывать основной функционал на боте. Основная работа закончена и он призван помочь с организацией и ведением клиентской базы. Он умеет записывать, редактировать БД и формирует полный рабочий день исходя из заданных параметров пользователем. Его основная цель это помощь в организации рабочего дня.

Но я зашёл сюда не похвастаться, как это показалось вначале =). Я хочу расширить его функционал, чтобы он мне делал отчёты за день/неделю/месяц/год и строить всякие там красивые графики, прикольные циферки и чтобы это было миленько и приятненько.

Как я это вижу:
В боте я тыркаю кнопку "сделать отчёт", он делает нужную выборку по БД и отправляет это джанге, она в свою очередь их принимает, делает из набора цифр удобочитаемую структуру в виде html страницы и отправляет ссылку обратно боту, а он её отправляет пользователю в сообщении.
Бот написан при помощи flask(не спрашивайте как, просто взял пример из видеоурока а дальше дописывал логику бота), pythonanywhere, и PyTelegramBotapi и встроенная sqlite3 
Посему у меня вопрос к знатокам.
Подскажите что мне надо гуглить и какое взаимодействие должно быть между ботом и сервером на джанге. Объясните пожалуйста на пальцах, что мне надо гуглить. 
ЗЫ
Да, я уверен, что хочу сделать именно такое взаимодействие, нет я не хочу расширять функционал flask-a. Да я понимаю, что скорее всего это будет через костыли и через "йоптвоюмедь" и тонна говнокода. 
Главная моя цель это освоить джангу, потому что интересно, а писать блоги из видеоуроков скучно.
Если вы дочитали до этого момента, значит я не настолько безнадежен. Если есть какие мануалы на эту тему(джанго с нуля я уже читаю и смотрю), то ткните пожалуйста в ссылку.

Comment: Requests + json post + url на django. Ничего сложного...

Comment: Благодарю за наводку, после некоторого погружения в тему, все оказалось действительно проще, чем представлялось вначале